# Options to respond_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am reading chapter 13 in Rails 3 in Action and I use a hash `:methods => "last_ticket"` in the respond_with method. However I don't understand what this does and where I find what options I can pass to respond_with. Can somebody tell me where I find it?

Comment: Could you post a code block of what code looks like?

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby API documentation for the [Responder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html) object explains about custom options that you can pass into respond_with. Excerpt from the doc:

> respond_with also allows you to pass options that are forwarded to the
>   underlying render call. Those options are only applied for success
>   scenarios.

In your case, I believe result of the successful request will be passed onto a method called "last_ticket"(defined in the same controller). This tutorial shows you some practical use as well as the meaning of respond_with [What's New in Edge Rails: Cleaner RESTful Controllers w/ respond_with](http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/6/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-cleaner-restful-controllers-w-respond_with/)

Hope it helps